# open source Flutter Web PDF Viewer using network file link solution?

Tags: flutter, pdf, syncfusion, pdf.js

Was Using Syncfusion PDF Viewer but it's displaying grey screen upon release. Any other alternative solutions for pdf viewers in Flutter Web that supports network file?

Answer (score 0):

For the web platform, we have used PdfJs for rendering the PDF pages, so the script file must be referred to in your web/index.html file. On your web/index.html file, add the following script tags, somewhere in the head or body of the document:

Script:

pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.4.456/pdf.worker.min.js";

UG documentation link: https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/pdf-viewer/getting-started#add-the-flutter-pdf-viewer-to-an-application

To load PDF from network using SfPdfViewer.network in macOS, network access must be enabled in your macOS application. On your macos/Runner/DebugProfile.entitlements file, add the following lines inside the  tag to enable the network access in your application:

com.apple.security.network.client

UG documentation link: https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/pdf-viewer/getting-started#load-document-from-the-network

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution.

So, this is the output of the below-mentioned source code: [View](https://i.postimg.cc/k5TyVZJm/Screenshot-2023-08-29-at-11-56-07-AM.png)

Source code:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  PdfControllerPinch? pdfController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (Duration timeStamp) async {
        const String url = "https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf";
        final Uri parsedUri = Uri.parse(url);
        final Response res = await get(parsedUri);
        final Future<PdfDocument> doc = PdfDocument.openData(res.bodyBytes);
        pdfController = PdfControllerPinch(document: doc);
        setState(() {});
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    pdfController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: pdfController != null
          ? PdfViewPinch(controller: pdfController!)
          : const CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }
```

Dependent packages: [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) & [pdfx](https://pub.dev/packages/pdfx)

Note: After installing the [pdfx](https://pub.dev/packages/pdfx) package, run the below-mentioned command:

```
flutter pub run pdfx:install_web
```